# Repository Pattern and Unity Container.. create object in controller for entity/POCO

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

Working on web api using EF codefirst approach.

I want to use Dependency injection using Unity framework.
i downloaded--**Unity.webapi**, it addeds few unity files(unityconfig, unityresolver). my entities i registered as like attachment.

but my codefirst entities not implements any interfaces, all are plain code first classes. now i want to write **code in my controllers**. how to write ?

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();          
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext,PolicyInfo>));
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext, LossInformation>));
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext, Manufacturer>));
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext, ModelVariant>));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

**class**

```
public class **PolicyInfo** 
{
    [Key]
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PolicyIssuedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**controller**:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PolicyInfo")]
public class PolicyInfoController : ApiController
{
    GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext, PolicyInfo> policycontext;        
    public PolicyInfoController()
    {
        this.policycontext = new GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext, PolicyInfo>();                        
    }
}
```

I hope this is not write way to create context object. because i written `PolicyInfo` object at constructor level. please suggest any one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the key concepts behind Inversion of Control (IoC) and Dependency Injection (DI) is precisely not to have to manually instantiate the required dependencies inside the consumer class but those dependencies to get injected into the class.

So if you are using Unity or any other framework, the goal is to suppress the line where you are creating the object context by a parameter in this case in the constructor of your API Controller.

So you if your IoC container is properly configured you should be able to get a reference to the GenericRepository using e.g, constructor injection:

Try this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PolicyInfo")]
public class PolicyInfoController : ApiController
{
    IGenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext, PolicyInfo> policycontext;        

    public PolicyInfoController(IGenericRepository<ApplicationContext,PolicyInfo> policyContext)
    {
        //use the context here... e.g.: Save the reference to the instance field.
        this.policyContext = policyContext;
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest a bit more of abstraction in your code in order to make it clearer and more efficient.

Take a look a [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection), although a little old, still applies perfectly to your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: slight typo in code. you can't assign interface to class. check policycontext instance field.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, fixed!